# Confusion over dentability and denting points

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

I'm trying to learn about dentable sets and denting points in Banach spaces, but I'm running into some trouble. Part of the issue is that I've attacked this topic in a really sloppy, disorganised manner, and so I'm left with some loose ends that I need to tie up.

As I understand it, a closed, bounded, non-empty, convex set $C$ is dentable if it contains a slice of arbitrarily small diameter, and a point $x \in C$ is a denting point if it is contained in slices of arbitrarily small diameter.

Then, equivalent to the set having Radon-Nikodym property, there's the property that every closed, non-empty subset of $C$ is dentable. From previous reading, I seem to remember that this should imply that $C$ is the closed convex hull of its denting points.

Firstly, is this true? I was thinking that, as a way to prove it, you'd take an arbitrary slice $S_0$ of $C$, and show it has a denting point. Because all closed, convex, non-empty subsets of $C$ have aribtrarily small slices, you could find a slice $S_1$ of $S_0$ with diameter less than $1$, a slice of $S_1$ with diameter less than $\frac{1}{2}$, and recursively take further slices $S_n$ of $S_{n-1}$ with diameter less than $\frac{1}{n}$. Then, these nested closed sets must have a unique point of intersection, which is a denting point.

The problem with this approach is that a slice of a slice is not necessarily a slice, as illustrated by this picture:
[image]
The yellow region is a slice of the yellow and blue region, which is a slice of the larger triangle. But, the yellow region isn't a slice of the larger triangle. How can I fix the above proof? Can I fix the above proof?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that this difficulty can be overcome if you use strongly exposed points rather than dentable points, in which case the slices with shrinking diameter can be taken to be nested. It is true that a closed, bounded, convex set with RNP is the closed, convex hull of its strongly exposed points (this is due to Bishop and Phelps, and can be found in the book of Bourgin "Geometric Aspects of Convex Sets with the Radon-Nikodym Property"). This is stronger than saying it is the closed, convex hull of its dentable points, I believe.

Comment: @user114263 Thank you for the resource! I've found it, and I'll look through it in detail tomorrow. I don't suppose you could point me to an example of a closed, bounded, convex set that is the closed convex hull of its denting points, but not its strongly exposed points? I was under the impression that the conditions were equivalent, but I have no idea where I read this.

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but I think Theorem 2.3.6 of Bourgin's book may yield both of these conditions (being the closed, convex hull of its strongly exposed points and the closed, convex hull of its dentable points) are equivalent to the set having RNP.

Comment: The theorem says that C has the RNP iff every closed convex bounded subset is the closed convex hull of its denting points iff every closed convex bounded subset is the closed convex hull of its strongly exposed points. This leaves the possibility open that C is the closed convex hull of its denting points without having a single strongly exposed point. (Of course, such a C won't have the RNP). Unfortunately, I don't have an example to this effect at hand...

Comment: Would who ever voted to close this as "off-topic" like to explain their reasoning? Dentability and the RNP seem very much on-topic to me.